# Implementing SwipeRefreshLayout with a view that is not the current view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, swiperefreshlayout

I am trying to implement swipe to refresh. However the refresh view is in a fragment that gets inflated once an rss feed is loaded. This code does not crash the app, however the refresh view stays indefinitely and does not take on any of the attributes I have given it.

```
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_rss, null);
SwipeRefreshLayout refresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) 
v.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
refresh.setEnabled(true);
refresh.setColorSchemeColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), 
     getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary), 
     getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
refresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() 
    {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        new refresh().execute("");
    }
});
```

`new refresh().execute("");` calls an async animation that then calls the refresh method once the animation is complete.

```
private class refresh extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return "Interrupted";
        }
        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        refreshRssFragment();
    }
}
```

And here's the XML

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/newsList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

This is the refreshRssFragment() method

```
 private void refreshRssFragment(){
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    RssFragment fragment = new RssFragment();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
    refresh.setRefreshing(false);
}`
```

Comment: you should call refresh.setRefreshing(false) to stop refreshing..

Comment: private void refreshRssFragment(){
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        RssFragment fragment = new RssFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
        refresh.setRefreshing(false);
    } I have that already :/